# What is the difference between these two ways to invoke base class copy assignment?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    A& operator= (A const& other)
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B& operator= (B const& other)
    {
        static_cast<A&>(*this) = static_cast<A const&>(other);
        // or...
        A::operator=(other);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

To invoke `A`'s version of the copy assignment operator, I could do either:

```
static_cast<A&>(*this) = static_cast<A const&>(other);
```

Or:

```
A::operator=(other);
```

Why would you choose one over the other? What are the differences between the two?

### EDIT

My question's initial example was invalid and very far off from what I was intending to ask. My apologies for the mistake. I have updated my example above to be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`static_cast<A&>(*this).foo()` still calls the derived version of `foo`. This is just calling a virtual function through base class reference.

Whereas `A::foo()` turns off virtual dispatch and calls `foo` implemented in class `A`, not in the derived class.

---

If `operator=` is not virtual in `A`, `static_cast<A&>(*this) = static_cast<A const&>(other)` is another way of saying `A::operator=(other)` (no need to upcast `other` because the derived to base reference conversion is implicit). They do the same thing - call `A::operator=`.

Often though, `operator=` is implemented in terms of copy constructor followed by swap:

```
B& B::operator=(B other) { 
    other.swap(*this); 
    return *this;
}
```

Taking `B` by value invokes `B`s copy constructor for us. If `B` has r-value copy constructor this assignment operator can be used with r-values as well as move-only `B` (if `B`, for example, has a `std::unique_ptr` member).

Comment: My example is incorrect, I need to revise it. Your answer is correct, my question is wrong. Apologies. Edits will follow.

Comment: Your usage of copy-swap has a strong exception safety guarantee. I doubt everyone needs this guarantee; doesn't this solution have performance implications?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the A assignment operator for both classes (A and B), simply don't implement it in the B class.